# Amazon UK in links are overwritten to US

Tags: bug, status-completed

When amazon.co.uk links are used (as in [this](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/5363/how-much-difference-does-malt-make-in-extract-brewing) post) they are redirected incorrectly to the US site.

ie http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B005KRFNS2/ will direct you to [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B005KRFNS2/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005KRFNS2)

Comment: Why has this been marked as status-compleated? These answers explain why the bug has happened but offer no work around or resolution.

Comment: Rebecca's answer says that UK links should no longer be rewritten to redirect, which is why she marked it as status completed. Is that not the case for the links you refer to? You'll probably need to re-add them to a post if they've already been redirected.

Comment: Ah ok. My bad :)

Answer (score 3):

Links that are not to the US .com Amazon site will no longer be redirected there.  We are not an affiliate in other countries.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon links are rewritten](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links) to include an affiliate link for the network. At one point, the did geolocate, but stopped after a while.

As to why they stopped geolocating, it was asked on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75594/150909) which got [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75594/auto-inserting-amazon-affiliate-links-take-me-to-the-wrong-amazon/92042#92042) that contains a quote from Jeff:

> It's a long story, but unless we operate a business in the UK,
>   officially, we can't get affiliate income from Amazon there anyway ..
>   so we don't geolocate amazon stuff any more, and have not for a while.

That answer also links to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/our-amazon-advertising-experiment/) about SO's experiments with Amazon links and advertizing.